optimization of haskell function
the function below counts number of vowel and consonant:
countVowelConsonant :: [Char] -> Int
countVowelConsonant cs = count v c cs
    where
        v = 0
        c = 0
    count :: Int -> Int -> [Char] -> Int
    count v c [] = comp v c 
        where 
            comp v c
                | v == c = 0
                | v > c = v
                | otherwise = c
    count v c (a:cs)
    | or [a == 'a', a == 'e', a == 'i', a == 'o', a == 'u'] = count (v+1) c cs
    | otherwise = count v (c+1) cs

main :: IO()
main = do
print $ countVowelConsonant ['a','l','l']

how can it be optimized further, it looks a bit messy

"he function below counts number of vowel and consonant" no it doesn't. It returns 0 for "ab" input. Unless you have your own definition of counting, in which case you should share it with us.

or [a == 'a', a == 'e', a == 'i', a == 'o', a == 'u'] can be written as a `elem` "aeiou". It isn't more efficient, but it's more readable.

yes it should returns 0, when there is equal number of consonant and vowel, unless i'm missing somthing

Well, it counts the number of vowels and consonants and does something (very strange) with the result to compute a single Int. That isn't clear from your description. Also, are you asking about optimisation or style advice?

@NaïmFavier: I think it should return the maximum of the number of vowels, and the number of consonant, unless they are equal then it is 0, which indeed does not make much sense.

@NaïmFavier: which part is strange, i'm new to haskell so i don't know if there is any undefined behaviour in th e function. about optimisation or styling? kind of both

@HabibullahArif: the where v = 0; c = 0 is very strange: variables in Haskell are immutable, so it makes not much sense to introduce v and c here, since you can use count 0 0 cs.

i did this because it show Variable not in scope error

This has nothing to do with Haskell: the mathematical function you are implementing is weird. Why return max(c, v) if c ≠ v but 0 otherwise?

so what shoud be the correct handling when c = v?

We can't tell you what behavior you should want from your function. But if we point out a behavior that we think is strange, and you can't say why you want it, then there's something odd going on. Presumably you wrote this function because you have some goal you want to achieve; can you tell us about that goal? (If there's no goal, then I propose countVowelConsonant cs = 0, which is both extremely fast and extremely concise.)

A fragment of the code like:
countVowelConsonant :: [Char] -> Int
    countVowelConsonant cs = count v c cs
        where
            v = 0
            c = 0

looks quite strange: in Haskell variables are immutable, so you can not increment or decrement v or c, so defining a variable v = 0, to then just pass it to a function is very strange.
But we don't really need this. We just need to implement a vowel check function:
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel 'a' = True
isVowel 'e' = True
isVowel 'i' = True
isVowel 'o' = True
isVowel 'u' = True
isVowel 'A' = True
isVowel 'E' = True
isVowel 'I' = True
isVowel 'O' = True
isVowel 'U' = True
isVowel _ = False

and then we count the number of vowels and consonants with:
countBoth :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
countBoth pred = go 0 0
  where
    go t f [] = (t, f)
    go t f (x : xs)
      | pred x = t `seq` go (t + 1) f xs
      | otherwise = f `seq` go t (f + 1) xs
then we can post-process the result, like:
countVowelConsonant :: String -> Int
countVowelConsonant cs = go (countBoth isVowel cs)
  where
    go (v, c)
      | v == c = 0
      | otherwise = max v c

You could implement it like this:
import Data.List (partition)

countVowelConsonant :: String -> Int
countVowelConsonant xs = max (length vs) (length cs)
    where (vs, cs) = partition (`elem` "aeiou") xs

partition is a function in the Data.List standard module that takes a a -> Bool function and a list (a String is just a list of characters) and splits it into a pair of lists, one where True was returned for each element, and the other where False was returned for each element.
To check if a character is a vowel, you can check if it's contained in a list of vowels (you can add more for the uppercase characters) using elem.
Then you can use destructuring assignment to get both lists, get the length of both of them, and return the higher length using max.
